# Check if a value exists between two numbers (float ) c#

Tags: c#, linq

I see Enumerable.Range(int x, int y).contains() is used to check if a value exists between two given values. But this works only for integers.

How to check for float values - all x, y and result are float values.

Comment: You cannot do this using Range because you are not able to generate all float numbes between any given x and y. Are you looking for `x <= q && q>= y` ?

Comment: If you want to see if a is between x and y, just do `x < a && a < y` even for `int` since the second argument to `Enumerable.Range` is length, not the end number.  So `Enumerable.Range(5,3)` is 5, 6, and 7.

Comment: Enumerable.Range generates a sequence of y integers with starting value x. Contains() is checking that the sequence contains a particular value - not that the value is between the first & last of the sequence. To do the same for floats you would need to generate a sequence of all possible floats in the range - so the above two solutions are the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The `Enumerable.Range` method generates a sequence of integral numbers within a specified range. So, if you call `Enumerable.Range(1, 10)` the result will be a list of 10 integers starting with 1.

If your intention is just to check if a value exists between two given values, you could just do that:

```
public static bool Between(float number, float min, float max)
{
    return number >= min && number <= max;
}
```

Comment: More correctly Enumerable.Range generates a sequence of y (2nd parameter) integers with starting value x (first parameter). - So Enumerable.Range(2, 10) would return a 10 integer list from 2 to 11, not a list from 2 to 10.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: If you really want the same LINQ form for some weird reason, try

```
...Range(BitConverter.ToUInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(x), 0), Bit...(y-x+1)).contains(Bit...(a));
```

This obviously won't work, but you might be able to massage it to the working solution if you really want to. Obviously don't do it.

Original post below:

Hum I don't understand the point of your checking for integers like that.

If you want to check if any value exists between 2 integers, subtract them and if abs(answer) is 2 or more, there is at least 1 between them. If you want to check if your integer is between 2 integers, do `x<a && a<y`.

For floats, if you want to check if any value exists, check their binary representation and subtract those. If you want to check if float is between 2 floats, do the same `x<a && a<y`.